# Using Wordpress.com API to retrieve featured images

Tags: media, rest-api, wordpress.com-hosting, endpoints

I'm using the wordpress.com API to access a blog's content:

https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2/sites/MYSITENUMBER/pages

It works great, I can access all the text content I need, however, I cannot access the **/media** endpoint to get the featured_image associated with each page. The media endpoint gives me a 401 error.

I can access that endpoint using the developers console:
https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/console/

Because I'm signed in as the owner of the site.

My question is, how do I properly retrieve the featured images? It seems crazy that I'd need to authenticate to gain access to the URL for each image which is publicly available anyways...

If it is the case that I need to auth, how do you do that with wordpress.com? I don't know much about authentication, so even just pointers in the right direction would be great! Thanks.

Comment: what does it have to do with wordpress the software?

Comment: The question is 'how do I retrieve images from the wordpress.com API?' which is related to wordpress...

Comment: Of course, if the answer is, 'you must authenticate', then that's an answer that helps me out...and I can continue my search in that direction...

Comment: Ok. I seem to have found my answer, in the Caveats section of the page here: https://developer.wordpress.com/2016/11/11/wordpress-rest-api-on-wordpress-com/

Comment: "In addition, a few endpoints are restricted or disabled on WordPress.com, generally for parity with our v1 API. A few examples:

- Listing and retrieving media items requires authentication..."

Comment: well, wordpress.com is obviously not wordpress.... just because something is called with similar name doesn't make it the same. It iis explicitly stated in the description of the tag

Answer (score 0):

Simple:  Add `?_embed` to the url query string.

Eg: `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed=true`  (`_embed` will work too )

You will then find a property within each post in the JSON called `_embedded` which will contain all the info you need for Featured Image.  Also your taxonomies/categories/tags etc.